# Change the page numbering of appendices and restart it

Tags: page-numbering

I'm making a document with KOMA Script, as usual, in fact with the `scrartcl` class. But I need to add at the end of the document an `\appendix` macro and after few appendices, but I need to make two things I'm not sure how to achieve it:

1. restart the page number counter afte the `\appendix` macro, and
2. number the following pages with uppercase letters: A, B, C, etc.

I was reading another related questions about change the number format for a whole document, or change it for an speciic section, but that isn't what I need exactly.

Maybe the following MWE can help to clarify the idea:

```
\documentclass[div=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}

Lorem ipsum sic dolor amet\ldots

\section{Another section}

Lorem ipsum sic dolor amet\ldots

\appendix

\section{An appendix}

Lorem ipsum sic dolor amet\ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` one possibility is defining `\appendixmore` in your preamble:

```
\newcommand\appendixmore{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \pagenumbering{Alph}%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[div=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand\appendixmore{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \pagenumbering{Alph}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Lorem ipsum sic dolor amet\ldots
\section{Another section}
Lorem ipsum sic dolor amet\ldots

\appendix
\section{An appendix}
Lorem ipsum sic dolor amet\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\cleardoubleoddpage`? I couldn't find it in the KOMA Script manual.

Comment: @IraultzaBelaustegigoitia From the KOMA-Script manual: "It is recommended to use `\cleardoubleoddpage` to close the last page and start a new odd page before `\pagenumbering{<numbering style>}`." `\cleardoubleoddpage` is explained in section 3.13. Interleaf Pages.

Comment: I saw the section 3.13 but there isn't any command that has exactly that name, there are several similar options, but since I'm making a document with the `scrartcl` class I don't need to leave double blank pages, so the `\clearpage` of all life is enough. However, all these KOMA Script options are interesting, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @IraultzaBelaustegigoitia You are right. For onesided documents `\clearpage` is  enough and for twosided with default `open=right` a `\cleardoublepage` does the job. `\cleardoubleoddpage` ensures that a right page is opened even if the document uses `twoside, open=left`. A possible blank page gets the page style set by option `cleardoublepage=<pagestyle>`. Default is `cleardoublepage=empty`. And you are right `\cleardoubleoddpage` is only short mentioned (not in the box with the commands) in the documentation but not really explained.